# Is there a word which means past and current but not future?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, one can refer to "past semesters" and to "the current semester", but if you want to refer to both of those while excluding future semesters?   Something more concise -- hopefully a single word -- than "the current and past semesters".  For example, like "extant" semesters, but better -- I'm not really sure "extant" means current + past.

Comment: would a 2 word phrase work for you?

Comment: It's for a web app where brevity is definitely helpful.

Comment: A short two word phrase might work.

Comment: I thought the word “erstwhile” would work for this, but evidently I had a slightly incorrect definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**to date**

> Up to the present time in history; until now.

As in:

> To date, the company has never released a product that generated less
>   than $100 million in profit. We've received no news to date from our
>   affiliate in Afghanistan.

**hitherto**  [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hitherto) works too and is one word but is used less.

> ```
> up to this time; until now
> ```

Comment: OP has tagged this solely 'single-word-requests', not 'phrase requests'. Though I'd certainly use 'To date, semesters ...'. And perhaps 'Semesters to date have been ...' is licensed here.

Comment: Interesting, I have always thought of hitherto as an adverb, but it looks like there is some use of it as an adjective (which is the part of speech I need).